# Page not loading when trying to handle forms

Tags: php, forms

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to handle a form so I added a `if` condition to check if the submit button was pressed and if the other elements in the form are set. For some reason it causes the page to not load (it loads, but shows a blank page) so I can't actually submit anything..

When I tried removing the php code, it loaded fine. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<body>
    <?php
    if(isset(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'aglogin')) && isset(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'agname')) && isset(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'agpass')))
    {
        echo 'Submitted..';
    }
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" id="agname" name="agname"/>
        <br>
        Password: <input type="password" id="agpass" name="agpass"/>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" id="aglogin" name="aglogin" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thats because you likely have some sort of fatal error going on. Post your code or put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your page.

Comment: @Rasclatt I have posted my code..

Comment: This is the total code on the page?

Comment: Yes, the rest are the `header` and `html` but I didn't touch them.

Comment: This is your error: `Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead) in /data/19/2/133/150/2948313/user/3268049/htdocs/123/123123/index.php on line 3`

Comment: @omar aviv - coding is our thing, not mind reading. Please post the code with which you are having issues otherwise nobody will know where you are going wrong

Comment: Put this at the top of your page `error_reporting(E_ALL);` then php will tell you what to fix

Comment: This syntax is not allowed: `isset(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'aglogin'))`

Comment: @Rasclatt What does it mean? As I said I'm pretty new to PHP.

Comment: I tried `isset($_POST['aglogin'])` too, but it said `do not access superglobal $_post array directly`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use isset(); because filter_input() returns true if variable is set and return false if it is not set.

```
<body>
<?php
if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'aglogin') && filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'agname') && filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'agpass'))
{
    echo 'Submitted..';
}
?>
<form method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" id="agname" name="agname"/>
    <br>
    Password: <input type="password" id="agpass" name="agpass"/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="aglogin" name="aglogin" value="Login">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        $valid=( array_key_exists('aglogin',$_POST ) && array_key_exists('agname',$_POST ) && array_key_exists('agpass',$_POST ) ) ? true : false;

        if( $valid ) echo "Form submitted successfully";

    }
?>
```